# i push an image to docker registry, but i cannot see it later?

Tags: docker, repository, pipeline

I push an image to docker registry via pipeline and i see the following in the logs:

```
/usr/bin/docker images
/usr/bin/docker push <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7655
REPOSITORY                                  TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
<some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump               7655        d57770eee265   1 second ago   404MB
<18_other_lines>
The push refers to repository [<some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump]
```

But when i later execute

```
docker image ls -a
```

only the
<18_other_lines>
appear,

and when i execute in another pipeline the following:

```
docker images <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7578
```

the result is empty:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/9c8c1b17-1f60-4710-997a-8f1a66f67e24.sh
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Any idea why this happens?
And by the way in the same pipeline, but in another job i execute:

```
      docker pull <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7578
      docker run --publish 3306:3306 <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7578
```

and i do not see errors in the log.

And all i need here is to see at which ip is the maria db image started, in order to connect to it via python code.

Comment: If this is in a CI system, is something else cleaning up unused images underneath you?  Just `docker run` the image is always safe, and will pull it if it's not present locally.  I'm not clear about your final statement, since the container-private IPs are unusable in many environments and there are more portable alternatives, and also this seems unrelated to the image vanishing locally.

Comment: Yes, this is a CI system... i have to check about cleaning up unused images. But in the same pipeline, where i execute "docker image ls -a", i execute in another job "docker pull  <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7578" and "docker run  <some_repo_name>.azurecr.io/databasedump:7578" and i do not see errors in the logs.  ...Maybe these jobs are run simultaniously and the request for listing the images is done actually before the image is really pulled and started. And yes - my final statement is what i need at the end - what do you mean with "more portable alternatives"?

Comment: If you're making a call directly from the host, you can connect to `localhost` and the first `--publish` port.  If the caller is another container, `docker network create` a network, run both containers on the same `--network`, and the containers' `--name`s will be usable as host names with the services' standard ports (`--publish` is not used in this case).